# JSON.parse() в IOS7

Tags: javascript, json, safari

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse('[12,33,55]');
console.log( obj2 );
```

Во всех браузерах все ок, но iOS7 и ниже не парсит `obj2` и возвращает пустой . Решение [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211186/json-parse-is-not-working-on-ipad-safari) не сработало. Какие еще есть идеи? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать данный парсер JSON:

> https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js

Пример использования:

```
var obj = json_parse('[12,33,55]');
console.log(obj); // получаем массив [12, 33, 55]
```

Comment: Пробовал прежде чем написать на SO. Не помогло. Вопрос, кстати, решили тем что заглянули в ТЗ, а там поддержка выше iOS8.